# script.ts not found error TS6053: although i set rootDir and outDir in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I watched a lot of video where people set tsconfig.json how they like. But i am somehow getting error. I did like they did. By the way, i installed typescript globally and set Policy restriction to unrestricted. I'd been getting the same error before setting restriction.[image: tsconfig.json]

[image: error screen]

Answer (score 0):

I am supposed to use it with watch flag. Otherwise, I need to define paths. So, if you do not want to define any paths:

```bash
tsc -w
```

Otherwise:

```bash
tsc /src/script.ts /build/
```